# How can I separate my code into different functions in a javascript excel add in when I make use of the context and of await context.sync()?

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js, office-js

I have a Vue.js add in for Excel with a method that is as follows:

```js
getDataFromSourceDict (sourceDict, mainSheet, i) {
  window.Excel.run(async (context) => {
    //Some code...
    
    var data = {}
    var key, value, temp
    for (key in sourceDict) {
      value = parseInt(sourceDict[key])
      temp = mainSheet.getCell(i - 1, value - 1)
      temp.load(['values'])

      await context.sync()

      data[key] = temp.values
    }

    //More code...
  })
```

Since I'm using that same piece of code multiple times I want to split up the code and have a function that just runs that part and returns the dictionary. However I'm having trouble because I cant run await context.sync() inside a normal Vue method.

Edit 1:
I think I didn't explain myself correctly. I want to move the mentioned part on the first function to another function.

```js
methods: {
    copyFromDashboardToTable (sourceName, destinationName, configData) {
      window.Excel.run(async (context) => {
        // SOME CODE
        
         //I want to move out this code
         //Find first empty row
         var currentRow = 1
         var row = -1
         while (row === -1) {
           var cell = table.getCell(currentRow, 0)
           cell.load(['values'])
           await context.sync()
           var cellData = cell.values[0][0]
           if (cellData === '') {           
             row = currentRow
           }
           await context.sync()
           currentRow = currentRow + 1
         }
        
        // and call it with something like this
        // var row = this.getFirstEmptyRow(context)

        //MORE CODE
    },
    getFirstEmptyRow (context) {
      //Move code here
    }
```

I've tried adding async before the function declaration, adding "window.Excel.run(async (context) =>", and other things but I haven't been able to do it.

Comment: try `async getDataFromSourceDict (sourceDict, mainSheet, i) {...}`

Comment: @Sphinx Thank you for your response. I dont think that solves my problem. I added extra details to the question. I would appreciate your help again.